# Reference implementation of ASP.NET MVC using ViewModels, EditModels, and AutoMapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, automapper, reference-implementation, editmodel

A simple question: is there a good reference implementation of using ASP.NET MVC with an ORM, ViewModels, and EditModels (ideally using Automapper)?

I understand the benefits of using these purpose-specific models, but haven't been too happy with the result of the code I've written to use these so far.  A simple reference application showing how and where these aspects are applied in the MVC workflow would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jimmy Bogard gave an [excellent presentation](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/07/23/mvcconf-slides-and-code-posted.aspx) at MVCConf which is [worth checking out](http://www.viddler.com/explore/mvcconf/videos/1/).

Comment: watching it right now, and so far I have to say that it doesn't explicitly answer my question--but his code shows the answers when you look hard enough!  I'm at 4x Post-It notes of timestamps with 20 minutes left :-D

Comment: Jimmy's "Controllers on a Diet" talk turned out to be about the best example I ever found--although his talk wasn't specifically about my question, his code and it's path of execution showed how it's done and turned out to be a very good reference.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

http://whocanhelpme.codeplex.com/

Not sure if it's a *reference* implementation, but it tries to collect good ones.